# Equality that does not hold in general for Wolfram Alpha

Tags: trigonometry, solution-verification, wolfram-alpha

Why for WolframAlpha $\frac{|\sin(\frac{x}{2})|}{|\cos(\frac{x}{2})|}=\sqrt{\frac{|(1-cos(x))|}{|(1+cos(x))|}}$ is not true $\forall x$? [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt%28%7C1-cos%28x%29%7C%2F%7C1%2Bcos%28x%29%7C%29%3D%7Csin%28x%2F2%29%7C%2F%7Ccos%28x%2F2%29%7C)

In my opinion the equality holds since $\sin(\frac{x}{2})=\pm\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos{x}}{2}}$ and $\cos(\frac{x}{2})=\pm\sqrt{\frac{1+\cos{x}}{2}}$

Comment: Alpha did not say that the equation is not true. Of course, zero denominators are excluded. As usual, Alpha is right.

Comment: Using your file and asking for the plot https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+%28sqrt%28%7C1-cos%28x%29%7C%2F%7C1%2Bcos%28x%29%7C%29-%7Csin%28x%2F2%29%7C%2F%7Ccos%28x%2F2%29%7C%29+for+x%3D-Pi+to+Pi

Comment: I have not understood...this is true everywhere apart from the points where the denominators are $0$?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici What is up with that graph? That scared me.  Why does that happen?

Comment: @TymaGaidash. You only see $0$ values